# Как использовать изображение в моделях Джанго

Tags: python, python-3.x, django

Джанго не может найти путь к изображениям
setting.py

```
import os, sys

# Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))


PROJECT_ROOT = os.path.dirname(__file__)
sys.path.insert(0, os.path.join(PROJECT_ROOT, 'apps'))

# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = '!h869$36+^-is$a06!4==th9&npp6ksu*^uyp(36w!+a%w21#p'

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []

STATICFILES_DIRS = (os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),)
# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'homepage.apps.HomepageConfig',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'testsite.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [
            os.path.join(PROJECT_ROOT, 'templates')
        ],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'testsite.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    }
}


# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'ru'

TIME_ZONE = 'Europe/Moscow'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True

STATIC_URL = '/static/'

MEDIA_URL = '/media/'

MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(PROJECT_ROOT, 'media')

STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(PROJECT_ROOT, 'static')
```

views.py

```
def champs(request, champ_id):
    try:
        champ = Champion.objects.get( id = champ_id )
    except:
        raise Http404("Page is not found :|")

    return render(request, 'homepage/champs.html', {'champ': champ})
```

models.py

```
class Champion(models.Model):
    theme = models.ForeignKey(Theme, verbose_name = "Тема", on_delete = models.CASCADE, default = 0)
    champion_name = models.CharField("Имя чемпиона", max_length = 25, unique = True)
    champion_name2 = models.CharField("Прозвище чемпиона", max_length = 40, default = 0)
    champion_lor = models.TextField("История чемпиона")
    champion_role = models.CharField("Роль чемпиона", max_length = 30, default = 0)
    champion_image = models.ImageField("Фото чемпиона", upload_to = 'homepage', null = True, blank = True)
    champion_patch_date = models.CharField("Патч и дата выхода чемпиона", max_length = 100, default = 0)
    champion_money = models.CharField("Стоимость чемпиона", max_length = 50, default = 0)
    champion_line = models.CharField("Линия чемпиона", max_length = 30, default = 0)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.champion_name
```

champ.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
{% load static %}
<html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Champions</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'homepage/champ.css' %}">
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <h1>{{champ.champion_name}}</h1>
        <h3>{{champ.champion_name2}}</h3>
        <img src="{{MEDIA_URL}}{{champ.champion_image.url}}">
        <hr class = "hr_2">
        <p class = role_1>Класс:  <em class = "role">{{champ.champion_role}}</em></p>
        <p class = "money_1">Стоимость: <em class = "money">{{champ.champion_money}}</em></p>
        <p class = "line_1">Линия: <em class = "line">{{champ.champion_line}}</em></p>
        <p class = "patch_1">Дата выхода:<em class = "patch">{{champ.champion_patch_date}}</em></p>
        <p class = "lor"><em>{{champ.champion_lor}}</em></p>
        <hr class = "hr_1">
        <p class = "p_1">@Все права защищены</p>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

urls.py

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views
from django.conf.urls.static import static
from django.conf import settings

app_name = 'homepage'
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.home, name = 'home'),
    path('patch', views.patch, name = 'patch'),
    path('patch/patch<int:patch_id>', views.patches, name = 'patches'),
    path('champ', views.champ, name = 'champ'),
    path('champ/champ<int:champ_id>', views.champs, name = 'champs'),
    path('ivent', views.ivents, name = "ivents"),
    path('ivent/ivent<int:ivent_id>', views.ivent, name = 'ivent'),
    path('item', views.items, name = 'items'),
    path('item/item<int:item_id>', views.item, name = 'item'),
] + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

Когда я запускаю сайт то в консоли выводиться Not found /media/homepage/Azir.jpg
Я долго возился с setting.py по скольку считал что проблема в нем, но ни к чему не пришел
Последнее что я сделал это добавил вот этот кусок кода в urls.py

```
+ static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

К сожалению это не как не изменило ситуацию
Генерируется ссылка /media/homepage/Azir.jpg но она не работает, а ссылка с статикой /static/homepage/champs.css работает

Comment: может PROJECT_ROOT на BASE_DIR заменить все таки? 
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(PROJECT_ROOT, 'media') - у вас директория media, должна находится в PROJECT_ROOT. вы же понимаете?

Comment: Я пробовал BASE_DIR результат оказался таким же только media в итоге хранилась в разных местах. В media так же записывалась фотография, но как только я заходил на сайт фотография не отображалась, а консоль выводила: Not Found: /media/homepage/Azir.jpg  в независимости от BASE_DIR или PROJECT_ROOT